# How do I create a View Cart button in Website Payments Standard?

Tags: button, view, paypal, cart

I'm using Website Payments Standard.

I've created 2 Add to Cart buttons using the manager and they work fine.
If my buyer clicks the Continue Shopping button, he's returned to the catalogue page and can't see the cart.

How do I create a View Cart button, please ?

It doesn't appear in the Button factory.

Comment: This clearly isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

After you create your Add to Cart button, scroll down past the box where PayPal gives you your HTML code.  There's a section that says **Create more buttons**, and one of the options says **Create a View Cart button**.